# Why my VM is adding backslash on every backslash in recent command

Tags: csh

My company setups a new VM for me to work and I'm not really sure the configuration details of this VM. One interesting thing which is new to me is that I get an annoying backslash on every backslash I type in the recent command. e.g.

I first type the following awk line command in the prompt

```
awk '{print $1 " \\"} 1
```

the command will execute and print the 1st column with ***one*** backslash after that. Then when I want to execute this command again, I press "up" key to find this command it becomes

```
awk '{print $1 " \\\\"} 1
```

And I can't use this command as it will add **two** backslashes instead of one! If I type `history` to check this command, it is showing there are four backslashes in the command instead of two when I typed in as well.

I don't get this problem in my old VM, so it must be some setting problems in capturing recent commands and I'm not sure how to google this issue... Apparently I think this problem only exists in csh, which is my VM default login shell. when I change to bash, the history/recent command does not have this issue.

Appreciate anyone could help me with this.